# Ionic run iOS simulator and real device black screen

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, onesignal

I installed the project OneSignal plugin. And I realized all the directions. But when I run the application on the virtual phone as well as on the actual phone, I get a black screen problem. I get a report on xCode. Is this the cause of this?

```js
2017-11-01 11:52:42.016918+0300 Perakende Kart[34766:1066611] ERROR: Error! 
iOS Simulator does not support push! Please test on a real iOS device. 
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
```

Comment: Is it the only warning/error you get on the console? A full log might be useful

Comment: yes, that's the only mistake. @bubu